# PyDev pop-up closes eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I have successfully installed PyDev for eclipse onto my computer. When I try to start a new python project though I get a pop-up. The pop-up states:

*I'm reaching out for you today to ask for your help to keep PyDev properly supported.
PyDev is kept as an open source product and relies on contributions to remain being developed, so, if you feel that's a worthy goal, please take a look at http://pydev.org and contribute if you can.
Thank you,
Fabio
p.s.: Sorry for the dialog. It won't be shown again in this workspace after you click the "Read it" button.*

Then there are the options "Show later" or "Read it"

Whether I click "Show later", "Read it", or click on the link, eclipse always shuts down without warning. The pop-up occurs every time I try to open a python file or start a new PyDev project even if I clicked "Read it". How can I prevent this pop-up from occurring, or at the very least, prevent it from shutting down eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the pop-up. When I got it I clicked 'read it' and had no problems. Maybe there is something wrong with your installation. Did you try to re-install Eclipse and PyDev?

Comment: I think this was a bug which was just fixed: https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/commit/b56423e2ac8667572627bf1042d868c6310be3aa (will try to do a 3.8 release with it tomorrow).